# SQL: Copiar registros de uma coluna

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
*Utilizando: Mysql*
Tenho essa tabela chamada `Licencas`
Preciso pegar a coluna `empresa_id` e a `coluna_id` dessa TABELA

E passar esses dados dessas duas colunas para uma outra tabela **Chamada**
`condutors_empresas` que contem as colunas: `empresa_id` e `condutor_id`

Tentei passar esse Script abaixo  SQL mas não deu certo qual a forma correta?:

```
 UPDATE condutors_empresas
LEFT JOIN licencas
SET condutors_empresas.empresa_id = licencas.empresa_id
```

Porem ele me retorna esse erro:

```
#1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a 'SET condutors_empresas.empresa_id = licencas.empresa_id' na linha 3
```

[image: Tabela condutors_empresas esta vazia]

Tabela condutors_empresas esta vazia preciso passar os dados de Licencas pra ca

Comment: Mas estes valores de empresa_id já existem na tabela Chamada? O que você está atualizando? Não seria um INSERT desses dois campos existentes na tabela Licencas na tabela Chamada?

Comment: Não a tabela condutors_empresas está vazia, eu preciso pegar os dados da Tabela LICENCA a coluna empresa_id e condutor_id pegar esses dados e passar para a tabela condutors_empresas dentro da coluna empresa_id e condutor_id. vou colocar foto na descrição a tabela condutors_empresas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se sua tabela está vazia então você deve utilizar um INSERT e não um UPDATE.

```
INSERT INTO condutors_empresas(empresa_id, condutor_id) SELECT DISTINCT empresa_id, condutor_id FROM Licencas;
```

Comment: Deu certo amigão, muito obrigado.